# L'expression « se rendre compte à quel point » est-elle correcte ?

Tags: expressions

> Il nous faudra encore plus de temps pour nous **rendre compte à quel
>   point** des différences d’expériences peuvent façonner ce qu’on perçoit.

Cette phrase est-elle correcte ?

« *Se rendre compte à quel point* » sonne un peu bizarrement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est **juste**.

L'expression qui te trouble est l'association de *se rendre compte* + *[jusqu']à quel point*.

Tu peux la remplacer par *s'expliquer jusqu'à quel degré* :

> Il nous faudra encore plus de temps pour nous expliquer jusqu'à quel degré des différences d’expériences peuvent façonner ce qu’on perçoit.

Mais comme l'indiquent @[Chop](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14169/se-rendre-compte-%C3%A0-quel-point-correcte/14171#comment-26781) et @[Amphiteóth](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compte) dans leur commentaire, le sens désigne aussi la phase précédant celle de la compréhension pour désigner l'instant où l'on réalise la différence :

> Emploi pronom. réfl. Se rendre compte. Remarquer, comprendre, s'apercevoir.

Et donc le remplacement serait plutôt :

> Il nous faudra encore plus de temps pour réaliser jusqu'à quel degré des différences d’expériences peuvent façonner ce qu’on perçoit.

---

Tu utilises le sens suivant de [*rendre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/rendre) :

> **RENDRE** signifie également *Exprimer*, *représenter*.
>
> > - Cette copie ne rend pas bien l'original. [...]  Rendre nettement, clairement, vivement sa pensée. [...]
> > - Rendre des oracles, Prononcer des oracles. Rendre témoignage, Témoigner. Rendre un arrêt, une sentence, Prononcer un arrêt, une sentence.
> > - Rendre la justice, Exercer, administrer la justice. [...] Rendre justice à quelqu'un, Reconnaître son mérite, ses droits. [...]
> > - Rendre raison, Expliquer pourquoi on fait quelque chose, pourquoi quelque chose est ou se fait. [...] Rendre raison à quelqu'un, [...]
> > - **Rendre compte d'une chose**, La détailler, en donner l'explication. Rendre compte d'un, événement. Rendre compte de sa gestion. Rendre un compte détaillé de sa gérance. Rendre ses comptes. On dit aussi : **Se rendre compte d'une chose**, Se l'expliquer, en prendre nettement connaissance. Je me rends parfaitement compte de votre situation. Il ne s'est pas bien rendu compte de ce qui se passait.

Et ce sens de [*point*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/point) :

> **POINT** signifie aussi Degré, période. Le raisin est à son point de maturité, est au point de maturité convenable. Sa réputation est arrivée à un tel point qu'elle ne peut plus grandir. Il est permis de plaisanter, mais jusqu'à un certain point. Il s'inquiète de tout à un point que vous ne pouvez pas imaginer. Il est au plus haut point de sa carrière. Son insolence est arrivée au dernier point. J'ignore **jusqu'à quel point** il est permis d'avoir confiance en lui. Il signifie aussi Instant, moment, temps précis dans lequel on fait quelque chose. Sur le point de mourir, il déclara...

Comment: J'aurais plutôt utilisé « réaliser combien » plutôt que « s'expliquer ». Ta proposition implique de comprendre les raisons, alors que l'original n'est qu'un constat des faits.

Comment: @Yohann Merci Yohan, superbe réponse.

Comment: @Chop Merci, tu m'as bien compris !

Answer (score 1):

Cette expression est tout à fait correcte, elle peut même être utilisée sans problème à l'écrit quand on emploie un registre de langue élevé.

"Se rendre compte...". La préposition qui suit peut être *que*, *de*, etc. selon la nature grammaticale de ce qui suit.

- Je me rends compte *de* mon erreur (mon erreur: un groupe nominal).
  Je me rends compte de l'obscurité.
- Je me rends compte *que* je me suis trompé. (une proposition avec un verbe).
  Je me rends compte qu'il fait sombre. Etc.
- Je me rends compte *à quel point* je me suis trompé. (On a intercalé une expression qui renforce la gravité de l'erreur.)
  Tu ne sais pas à quel point je t'aime. (implique un degré élevé) = to which extent.

Expression 2: "À quel point" est utilisée pour marquer le degré, veut dire "à un degré élevé". *Point* ici signifie degré.

Je me rends compte à quel point je me suis trompé = je me rends compte que je me suis trompé de beaucoup, et surtout: je réalise toute l'ampleur de mon erreur.

Pour être encore plus littéraire, on pourra dire: Je me rends compte de l'étendue de mon erreur.

Comment: Merci Stéphane !

Answer (score 0):

«se rendre compte» means "to realize" (oneself) and «à quel point» means "to what extent". Putting the two together: «Je me suis rendu compte à quel point j'étais naïf» ("I realized to what extent I was naive").